# where to configure settings for "simple access" module drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I want to be able to add a group for the "simple acces " module in drupal 7, I have looked high and low for where in the admin I can do this , can't find it. using version 7.x-2.0-beta1 of simple access

Answer (score 0):

The module page says this "Access groups are based on roles" add roles are here

http://yousite.com/admin/people/permissions/roles

Comment: The settings page for simple access doesn't come out unless you do this : https://drupal.org/node/887108

Answer (score 0):

I had roles , the answer is this:
The settings page for simple access doesn't come out unless you do this : https://drupal.org/node/887108